# call C dll from C# complex structure

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, marshalling, dllimport

I have c dll came from outside of our group.

```
#pragma pack(push, 8)
typedef struct
{
    int int1;
    int int2;
    int int3;
    int int4;
    int int5;
    int int6;

    int int_array1[250];
    int int_array2[250];    
    int int_array3[250];
    int int_array4[250];
    int int_array5[250];    
    int int_array6[250];
}my_structure
#pragma pack(pop)



extern "C" {  

 __declspec(dllexport) void set_my_structure(my_structure mystruct);
 __declspec(dllexport) my_structure get_my_structure();

}
```

I am using the following code to call the dll from C#.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 8)]
public class MyStructure
{
    public int int1;
    public int int2;
    public int int3;
    public int int4;
    public int int5;
    public int int6;

    public int[] int_array1 = new int[250];
    public int[] int_array2  = new int[250];    
    public int[] int_array3 = new int[250];
    public int[] int_array4 = new int[250];
    public int[] int_array5 = new int[250]; 
    public int[] int_array6  = new int[250];
}

[DllImport(_dllName, EntryPoint = "set_my_structure", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern void SetMyStructure(MyStructure data);

[DllImport(_dllName, EntryPoint = "get_my_structure", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern MyStructure GetMyStructure();
```

However, the code throws exception and stuck in neutral gear when I call GetMyStructure method. What is wrong? What is the best approach to handle this?

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: You'll need to annotate your C# arrays as well. Creating the array will tell the marshaller nothing.

Comment: I added annotation [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 250] for each C# array. It still doesn't work. The error msg is VSHOST32.exe stops working.

Comment: Is the C DLL 32bit? If so, you won't be able to call it from a 64bit C# app. What's the exception say?

Comment: It is not an exception. Windows pops up message saying " vshost32.exe has stopped working.". I compiled C# code as 32 bit. I was able to get some integer variables. It seems it didn't complain when I called SetMyStructure.

Comment: You need to declare it as a struct not a class . and yes you do need ByValArray

Comment: I tried several things and still cannot find a solution for it. I did make it working using C++/CLI as bridge between the C dll and C# for complex structure.